# Packaging JAR with libraries of Bouncy Castle into single JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, bouncycastle

I made my own wrapper classes and I would like that wrapper classes to be used by anyone using my compiled JAR file.

This jar file also contained a lib folder and it has bouncy castle libraries as well, since the wrapper purpose is to make things easier for the caller. So now my library with name MyLibrary.JAR is built.

Now when I have included this jar as a library in another project I see the following error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/operator/OperatorCreationException

I checked MyLibrary.Jar file and found that inside there is another Lib folder and all the bouncy castle libraries are there, so why am I still seeing this error? My Library jar has these structure folders

[image]

Inside the lib folder I am having following libraries 
[image]

I am not interested in using manual zip and unzip jar and add these libraries I am looking for something I will set on the NetBeans and It will generate the JAR file along with the dependent bouncy castle libraies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found it , I need to add the build properties like below in order to have an automated build single library

```
 <target name="-post-jar">
    <jar jarfile="dist/PKIFrapper.jar" >
    <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcmail-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcpg-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bctest-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/commons-codec-1.10-javadoc.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/commons-codec-1.10-sources.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.3-javadoc.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.3-sources.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.3.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />

    <manifest>

        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyLibrary.*"/>
    </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```