# java bouncy-castle KeyAgreement.getInstance works in eclipse but throws Exception: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC when jared

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle, vert.x

hey so I've been trying to translate some spring code to vertx
and I have got this piece of code that uses bouncy castle

```
    private SecretKey calculateSecureSymetricKey(Key privateKey, Key receivedPublicKey) throws Exception {
    
    BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    KeyAgreement keyAgreement ;
    
    try {
        keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", bouncyCastleProvider);
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("failed in custom exception");
        System.out.println("==============================");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("==============================");
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    
    keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
    keyAgreement.doPhase(receivedPublicKey, true);
    byte[] sharedSecret = keyAgreement.generateSecret();
    ASN1ObjectIdentifier oid = NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_aes256_CBC;
    int keySize = 256;
    DHKDFParameters params = new DHKDFParameters(oid, keySize, sharedSecret, null);
    ECDHKEKGenerator kdf = new ECDHKEKGenerator(DigestFactory.createSHA256());
    kdf.init(params);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keySize / 8];
    kdf.generateBytes(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
    SecretKeySpec aes = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    return aes;

}
```

now when I run it in my IDE (eclipse) it works fine
but
when I use **maven** to make this into a jar with this *pom.xml*

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.62</version>
        <!-- <version>1.59</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.59</version> -->
        <version>1.62</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- some more pom here that I can post if you think it's relevant -->


    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>mytest.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <!-- <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId> -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I run `mvn clean install`
and try to run the jar I get this exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:143)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:278)
        at deanew.service.KeyExchangeService.calculateSecureSymetricKey(KeyExchangeService.java:93)
        at deanew.service.KeyExchangeService.generateSecretKeyFromResponse(KeyExchangeService.java:84)
        at deanew.service.DeaNewService.getSaredSecretKey(DeaNewService.java:82)
        at deanew.service.DeaNewService.getPersonInfo(DeaNewService.java:177)
        at deanew.service.DeaNewService.getOldPersonInfo(DeaNewService.java:94)
        at deanew.service.DeaServiceImpl.lambda$deaByPin$0(DeaServiceImpl.java:54)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:316)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: file:/C:/Users/97252/eclipse-workspace_zukit_se/mytest/target/myTest-0.0.1
-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar has unsigned entries - dea/dea.jks
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:459)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:314)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:257)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.ProviderVerifier.verify(ProviderVerifier.java:129)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProvider(JceSecurity.java:189)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:215)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:139)
        ... 13 more
```

so my questions are

1. does any one know what is the problem is with this code? or if it
2. this is an example code just to isolate the problem and see if I can compile the jar and give it as a
   depadency to the main project
   but the pom.xml I use in the main application uses the `maven-shade-plugin`
   insted of the `maven-assembly-plugin` I'm using in this example
   would this even work with vertx? bec

I think I made it clear but if I havent please tell me
thanks in advance

EDIT:

so far I also tried to download the jars and add them as a depndecy with scope "system"
like this

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <scope> system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.63.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1.63</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <scope> system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/bcprov-jdk15to18-1.63.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1.63</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
        <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I tried to adding Michael Fehr sulotion so now the build looks like this

```
    <build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <target name="-post-jar">
                    <jar jarfile="">
                        <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*" />
                        <zipfileset src="/src/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.63.jar"
                            excludes="META-INF/*" />

                        <zipfileset src="/src/lib/bcprov-jdk15to18-1.63.jar"
                            excludes="META-INF/*" />

                    </jar>
                </target>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>mytest.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and still has the same probems
any thoughts

and agian thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are using Bouncy Castle ("BC") as a crypto provider in your program. The BC-jars
are digitally signed to prevent from any unwanted changes. When running the program in
your IDE the jars are loaded from the classpath and everything is running.

Now you are building a new jar with your program classes including BC-classes.
Your maven script will unzip the BC-jar (if you don't know - juste rename .jar to
.zip and open it, you will see the contents of the BC jar) and put all classes
together and generates a single jar.

So far so good but when having a look into the BC jar (here bcprov-jdk15to18-165.jar)
and folder META-INF there are some files with an ending "DSA" and "RSA"). What
are these files good for? They hold digital signatures to prove that the jar is unchanged.

The problem is: the signatures does not match the new content where they are including
other classes from you and other 3rd party libs.

One solution is to provide the external libs separate from your program app.

One other solution is to exclude those jars from beeing unzipped. There are several
Q&As here on SO, one possible solution (not tested by me) is this script for maven:
(taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44345254/8166854):

```
 <target name="-post-jar">
    <jar jarfile="dist/PKIFrapper.jar" >
    <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcmail-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcpg-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/bctest-jdk15on-155.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/commons-codec-1.10-javadoc.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/commons-codec-1.10-sources.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.3-javadoc.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.3-sources.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="src/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.3.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />

    <manifest>

        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyLibrary.*"/>
    </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

**But beware: the signatures may have an effect on some crypto functions as they may not work or as expected.**

Comment: hey so I've tried this now and it also doesn't seem to work I changed the relevant bouncy castle jar path to my relvent location and it still has the same problem 
the only thing I dint change are the  "<jar jarfile="dist/PKIFrapper.jar" >"
and " <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*" />" 
lines any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Refer [Similar issue](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/557) and [official notes](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

a. Try with JDK 8

b. Use 'bcprov-jdk15to18', version: '1.63' - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15to18